# What's the meaning of the continuity in spectrum analysis?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, orthornormal

We all know that for any, **suitable**, kind of signal $f(t)$,  there corresponds a Fourier transform function $F(j\omega)$ such that
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(j\omega) e^{i\omega t} d\omega
$$

So, $F(j\omega)$ can be recognized as the component of $f(t)$ along $e^{i \omega t}$. This is similar to orthogonal analysis. Like a cartesian vector $\vec{a} = (1,2,3)$ can be represented as 
$$ 
\vec{a}=  1\hat{x}+2\hat{y}+3\hat{z}
$$
where  $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$ are the orthonormal basis vectors (unit vectors along x-y-z directions).

However, these two things are different in one perspective.Among $x$,$y$,$z$, there is no concept as 'distance'. For example, in Fourier transform. we can say that the distance between $\omega_1 = 1$ and $\omega_2=2$ is smaller than the distance between $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3 =4$.

This algebra structure in Fourier transform definitely has some extra meaning, but what is it? Does it mean that the Fourier transform makes "more sense" compared with other orthonormal basis analyses where there is no easily-definable distance between basis functions?

Comment: what's "normal spectrum analysis"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I mean some orthonormal  basis without 'distance' structure

Comment: "orthonormal" implies the existance of a distance metric.

Comment: otherwise, you can't say "normal".

Comment: @MarcusMüller The 'distance' I mentioned is that the distance between the orthonormal basis. I think the 'distance' you considered is the distance between two signals. That is different

Comment: @MarcusMüller Besides, as for spectrum analysis, I implies that any kind of orthonormal representation with any kind of orthonormal basis

Comment: a basis is what gives you the ability to represent signals as sets of coefficients with respect to that basis. Having a basis and a length function defined thereupon hence directly implies measurability of the space spanned by that basis.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are absolutely right. You stated that the signal is measurable with respect to any basis. We know given any two basis vectors, they are orthogonal, so does the Fourier basis. However, between  Fourier basis, there exists some kind of 'distance'. For example, we say there are 90Hz 'distance' from 10Hz to 100Hz. But we can't say some 'distance' from x axis to y axis. In this situation, orthonormal basis like x axis is what I said normal one

Comment: well, the fact that you can assign a quality "frequency" to Fourier basis vectors is what is missing for your cartesian coordinate system, indeed. But you want to do *frequency analysis*, so for every sensible basis to do so, your basis will have some frequency-related property, and hence, you could declare the frequency differences to be "distances".

Comment: A frequency-related analysis has similar property as the Fourier analysis. But not each orthonormal analysis has it. So my question is the meaning or significance  of this property.

Comment: well... it's the *frequency* of the respective component... the periodicity of the signal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  well, it is intuitive. I just want to get more general perspective in orthogonal analysis other than Fourier analysis.

Comment: you will have to define what exactly you're considering, then. Fourier analysis is pretty much what everything breaks down to if you need to consider harmonic signals with non-symmetric spectra.

Comment: I'm voting to close unless we can get a clear definition of what you mean by "special" or "more sense" (my interpretation in the edit to your question).

Answer (score 2):

Let $v(x, k)$ be an orthonormal set of basis functions such that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} v(x,a) v^*(x,b) dx = \delta_{a,b}
$$
where $\delta_{a,b}$ s the [Kronecker delta.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerDelta.html)

I believe your question boils down to: for the Fourier Transform, we have
$$
v(x,a) = e^{jax}
$$
and we interpret $a$ as the frequency and $x$ as time; is there anything special about this orthonormal basis **because** we can interpret $a$ as a "distance" between these functions?

An example of another set of functions that are orthonormal (but over a finite interval) are the [Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):
$$
v(x,a) = P_a(x), \mbox{where} -1\le x \le +1
$$
where now $a$ is the order (degree) of the polynomial.

For these (and other polynomial bases), the "distance" is now the difference in polynomial degree.

Whether this means such functions are "less" special than the Fourier bases is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and a really tricky one to get your head around. I think your dual use of the word distance, and the comparison of vectors in an infinite function space to a vector in a finite-support sequence is a bit confusing.

The *distance* you're describing is the difference between the frequencies $w_1$, and $w_2$ of two sinusoids. In the time-domain it's easy to understand this difference because the two signals are completely localised in frequency (but specified for infinite time).

Once you've performed the Fourier transform, these signals are represented in a infinite space where sinusoids of any frequency are orthogonal to sinusoids of any other frequency. At this point, as you rightly describe, the sinusoids form an infinite orthogonal (basis) set. It feels strange, but in this space the inner product of 1Hz and 2Hz is the same as that of 1Hz and 4Hz. They're both zero! I think this is your other interpretation of *distance* - where a short distance would be a large inner product and a long distance a small inner product.

The reason this feels wrong is that we can still intuitively arrange the components of this infinite space in order of increasing $w$, so one component can still be 2Hz away from another. This is not the same as the distances represented by the inner products in the space generated by the Fourier transform.